# Consume Remote API in Laravel with Nodejs and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, laravel

I need some help in my project:

I have one API created in Laravel 5 with MongoDB this found fine, I make test with postman and I can login, logout, refresh token and CRUD of all my collections, for authenticated I use laravel/passport.

I created a simple client in nodejs + express and angular

the diagran it's

[image]

but I need make all request to api in node for the security no directly in angular, some this

[image]

to make request to API in node I can use node-rest-client, but I do not know how to send the answer to angular and how to call methods created in node when I use a button click for example, someone could help me

sorry for my English and the pictures

Comment: Using duo server side Node JS and Laravel API. Why don't you call the API directly and  make that secure?

Comment: Because the client needs it this way, it only wants the API in php and the client in Angular using node, thank very much for reply

Answer (score 1):

It will not be a complete solution but a direction for you, a simple **Node JS** app to call on your API will be like

Use `Express JS` for routes and `Request` for your API Calls

```
var _request = require('request'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
var _express = require('express'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
var _app = new _express();

# binding routes to your app
_app.post('/auth', function(request, response){
   _request.post(
     '/api/auth', // URL
     { username: 'John', password: '######'},
     , function(error, httpResponse, body){
         if(err){
             res.json("Error.");
         }

         // 'body' is the response of your API Request
       }
    );

   // OR GET Request

   _request.get(
     '/api/data', // URL         
     , function(error, httpResponse, body){
         if(err){
             res.json("Error.");
         }

         // 'body' is the response of your API Request
       }
    );
});
```

I hope this will get you started a bit. Thanks

Comment: thank very much, and now, why send the httpResponse data to frontend in angular o use in te $scope

Comment: I am not sure i am getting the above statement. can you please explain a bit ?